# Convert a vector in a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm starting on C++ and I don't really know how to do this. I have a `vector<int>` and I need to converted in a `vector<vector<int> >`.

Could you help me to do this?

Comment: Well, you can write `vector<vector<int>> b = {vector<int>()};`. On a more serious note, we need to know  _why_ do you want to do it in order to give a decent answer.

Comment: We need to know how you want it sorted.

Comment: I need to compute the Manhattan distance on it, so that's why I want to convert it in a vector of vectors, because I don't know how to do it on a vector.

Comment: Manhattan distance is counted between points. Does your vector contain point coordinates? For example, does a vector that contains `{1,1,2,2}` represent two points with (1,1) and (2,2) coordinates?

Comment: My idea is to compute distances on a multidimensional vector, I don't know how to do it on a unidimensional vector.